# Push from a tableView to a MFMailComposerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm currently developing an app where I have a static tableView with 7 sections. These sections are different courses that the user can apply to and what I want to accomplish is when the user clicks the row / button of a section. It pushes a `MailComposerView` and inside the mail It says for example,

> Hi I would like to apply to course %@ which accrues at this date %@. The %@ being the selected course and date.

Pleas tell me If I need to add more information / code.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the question? Do you want to show a Mail composer when you tap on a UITableViewCell?

Comment: Yes and with the information from the selected cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make use of the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of your UITableView. Try something like below:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 
    mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setSubject:@"Course Apply"]; //Set the subject here
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // this gets the currently selected cell.. Hope in your case, it's a custom cell. 
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi I would like to apply to course %@ which accrues at this date %@",cell.courseSelected,cell.courseData] isHTML:NO]; //courseSelected and courseDate are properties that hold value in your custom cell
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"your.email@email.com"];
    [mailViewController setToRecipients:toRecipients]; // set the recipient address here
    [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; // and finally present it... 
}
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Import `<MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` and `<MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>` into your viewController and add the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` to your Interface.

Use this code to show `MailComposeView`:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailViewController setSubject:@"<subject here>"]
[mailViewController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"your.email@email.com"];
[mailViewController setToRecipients:toRecipients];

[self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And this to dismiss the `MailComposeView`:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If you want to have different body text then put the code in a method which accepts `NSString` parameter and call that from the button or the selection method of the row and give it the text you want to have in the body.

Comment: Thanks i knew that part but I think Im going to go with another method so Im closing this question.